# Rotating values in a 2D matrix

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

So I was looking at a problem and I just cant figure it out. At least not in any manner I am happy with.

how do you rotate values in a 2D array.

So if the array is

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

After rotating it should be

```
4 1 2
7 5 3
8 9 6
```

The input is from a file where the first value is the number of rows/columns. So it can be a 2 x2 matric, a 3x 3 matrix, a 4x4 matrix, etc.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: what have you tried, where did you got stuck and what's the problem with your own tentative?

Comment: If it is a matrix of `5x5`, does only the outer "ring" rotate, or also the middle one? if so, how exactly?

Comment: Its only ever the outer ring that rotates. So the edges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping in a circle:

```
int x=0, y=0;
int prev = matr[0][0];
do{
if (x==0 && y<dim){ // move right on top row
    y++;
}
else if(y==dim-1 && x<dim){ // move down
    x++;
}
else if(x==dim-1 && y>0){ // move left on bottom row
    y--;
}
else{
    x--;
}
curr = matr[x][y];
matr[x][y] = prev;
prev = curr;
}while (x==0 && y==0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much as an algorithm as it is a simple solution.

I think the answer to this can be made up of 4 sub methods: `MoveTopRow()`, `MoveBottomRow()`, `MoveLeftColumn()` and `MoveRightColumn()`.

Generally speaking, create a new matrix and fill in the values using these methods. For example:

```
void MoveTopRow(int dimention)
{
     new_matrix[0][0] = old_matrix[1][0];
     for (int i = 1 ; i < dimention ; i++)
     {
         new_matrix[0][i] = old_matrix[0][i-1];
     }
}
```

I think the rest of the methods are self explanatory...

Comment: Cheers. This was actually one of the ways I was considering alright (before I ran out of time). And itll work, but its pretty brute forced. Just curious if there is a better way?

Comment: Inefficient, you create a secondary matrix

Comment: @discodowney - you are doing the minimal number of assignments here. Yes, the iteration is more actions, but unless you prepare a list of "moves" for each possible input `n`, I don't know how you can do it.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie - You could (with a bit more effort, hold a `int temp` that keeps the overridden value between loops and this way you don't need a secondary matrix. Also notice you need to fill in the middle (for `n>2`) which I didn't mention. I was aiming to give the idea.

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov you don't need to fill middle, check question comments. Well, yes, for a better answer you should have taken the effort and used that rather then a secondary matrix (that's why I gave you my comment...)